# Querying multiple mongo collections and combining specific attributes from results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to query a Mongo collection, then use an attribute from each object returned to grab data from another collection that also contains objects with that attribute. Then return and combine the data , I am not sure how to do this on mongoDB, broken down what I am trying to do is:

Query a mongoDB collection called "products" that contains objects like like this one:

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c5a0c707b446fc601e29"),
    "userName" : "test@test.com",
    "userId" : "aaa1",
    "headline" : "Test 01",
    "description" : "test 01",
    "durations" : [ 
        {
            "duration" : 15,
            "price" : "1.00",
            "GBP" : "1.00"
        }
    ],
    "categories" : [ 
        "testing"
    ],
    "id" : "MAnUNJDC62",
    "currency" : "£",
    "currencyCode" : "GBP",
    "leaderFirstName" : "Test",
    "leaderLastName" : "Test",
    "createddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T18:27:44.821Z"),
    "lastmodifieddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T19:54:03.568Z"),
    "lasttranslateddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T18:27:44.810Z"),
    "foreignheadline" : "test foreign",
    "foreigndescription" : "test foreign",
    "Rank" : 5,
    "avatar" : "test.png",
    "banner" : "test.jpg"
}
```

Grab the userName from each object in this collection and query another collection for any matches, the other collection has objects that are like:

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c58ec707b446fc601e24"),
    "userName" : "aaa1",
    "headline" : "testing test",
    "biography" : "testing",
    "availability" : "99999",
    "languages" : [ 
        {
            "language" : "English",
            "level" : "High"
        }
    ],
    "certifications" : [GCSES],
    "ppId" : null,
    "ppForm" : null,
    "ppSubmitted" : null,
    "created" : ISODate("2018-02-18T18:27:26.450Z"),
    "lastmodifieddate" : ISODate("2018-02-22T11:26:23.176Z"),
    "lastforeignchangeddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T18:27:26.445Z"),
    "foreignheadline" : null,
    "foreignbiography" : null,
    "totalreviewscore" : 8,
    "numberofreviews" : 2

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Then for each userName match grab the following:

- totalreviewscore : 8,
- numberofreviews" : 2

Return these two attributes alongside the object the username was initially taken from.

In the array each object would look something like :

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a89c5a0c707b446fc601e29"),
    "userName" : "test@test.com",
    "userId" : "aaa1",
    "headline" : "Test 01",
    "description" : "test 01",
    "durations" : [ 
        {
            "duration" : 15,
            "price" : "1.00",
            "GBP" : "1.00"
        }
    ],
    "categories" : [ 
        "testing"
    ],
    "id" : "MAnUNJDC62",
    "currency" : "£",
    "currencyCode" : "GBP",
    "leaderFirstName" : "Test",
    "leaderLastName" : "Test",
    "createddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T18:27:44.821Z"),
    "lastmodifieddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T19:54:03.568Z"),
    "lasttranslateddate" : ISODate("2018-02-18T18:27:44.810Z"),
    "foreignheadline" : "test foreign",
    "foreigndescription" : "test foreign",
    "rank" : 5,
    "avatar" : "test.png",
    "banner" : "test.jpg",
    "totalreviewscore" : 8,
    "numberofreviews" : 2
}
```

Essentially this seems like a join and I have looked at using $lookUp but could not figure out how to get it working whilst returning the two attributes with the objects used initially in an array.

Any pointers/tips on what to look at or on how this would at least work would be appreciated I am new to MongoDb and Node.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    { $lookup:
        {
            from: "profiles",
            localField: "userName",
            foreignField: "userName",
            as: "profile"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "totalreviewscore": "$profile.totalreviewscore",
            "numberofreviews": "$profile.numberofreviews",
            "profile": null
        }
    }
]);
```

The two added fields are array containing all values collected during the lookup stage, since in general it is possible to have a one-to-many binding.

Should you prefer a scalar value, you can change the last stage as follows:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "totalreviewscore": { $avg: "$profile.totalreviewscore" },
        "numberofreviews": { $sum: "$profile.numberofreviews"},
        "profile": null
    }
}
```